# Copyright removal of free template GNU/GPL

Tags: templates, commercial

Is it illegal to remove the copyright of free templates licensed under GNU/GPL,
if the site is just for non-commercial purpose?

As an example the copyright below the footer of the site?

[image: Footer copyright]

To get more specific, here the template of my choice licensed under GNU/GPL

[Joomla51 Free Template Oxygen](http://www.joomla51.com/free-templates)

Comment: Remove the copyright from where? Are you using the template on your website and it displays a copyright at the bottom of the front-end output?

Comment: The bottom copyright on front-end

Comment: It's really impossible to answer this question without checking the license and asking a lawyer. There are so many different scenarios for this and only a lawyer who does due diligence and proves you will be able to do it.

Comment: Also the same with code copyright, as in 3rd party free phps or stylesheets?

Comment: I just checked in Joomla51 templates, and none of them seem to be "free", could you tell us the name of the template?

http://www.joomla51.com/joomla-templates?layout=columns&category_id=1

Edit: Just found a Free template, Oxigen is it that one? license in that is GNU/GPL so you should be able to remove the copyright, although not a nice move, counting they are giving it free ;)

http://www.joomla51.com/free-templates

Comment: I think in GNU/GPL it's not sure to remove the copyright. Maybe a "made by " or a "in association with" but not a copyright. Maybe then I should edit the post to ask for GNU/GPL license instead ?

Comment: That line is showing in the template, so you can modify it, the copyright remains them, but as GPL you're free to modify it's looks

Comment: GPL allows you to change the code as you like, as long as you do not remove internal credits to the creator.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unless the author of the template made it a specific condition of downloading the template, you can remove any markup from the template, and that would include this-template-build-by-X links.

Comment: That would be the most respectful thing to do, but even if they said you can't edit it, if they licensed it as GPL, you can do what you want with it, including modifying it under the terms of the GPL.

Comment: The only problem I can think of even with a GPL template is it their backlink is the only copyright notice for the code. But even if that was the case, you could still just comment out that HTML and still be ok (because you aren't removing it, just hiding it from view).

Comment: From my understanding, the copyright needs to be available upon distribution and a SaaS like delivery does not count as distribution. So as long as the notice remains some where in the code (PHP comment) it should be fine.

Comment: The question used a downloadable template as the example. SaaS opens up another can of worms because they may impose additional conditions in order to use the service.

Comment: Joomla was GPL, now is....even more GPL to my understanding.

You can make any changes to the code you want, as long as you leave the original credit in the comments.

Here is the original reference to the GPL license:
https://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html

Comment: Just as an archival footnote, I think Andrew's wrong here. GPL doesn't allow you to place conditions on future use; once they download it they're free to do what they want. They could use it for a child-sex ring or to organize baby-seal-clubbing parties, and the developer has no recourse under GPL to prevent them. I think the proper way to handle the OP is to tack a "display: none" in the css for the notice. The copyright notice stays with the template (a requirement of GPL, IIRC) but out of the visitor's face (GPL doesn't entitle a developer to free advertising).

Answer (score 3):

As Don said be sure to first read the conditions of use. If your questions are not answered and there is still some doubt simply send a request to the creator asking permission for the removal of the copyright link. They may set some conditions for you to abide by. Asking will clear all doubts and future proof you and your client.

Comment: The original question did say for "non-commercial" purposes. So I assume it would not be for a client site.

Comment: I can only find Peter Bass from the Gold Coast.  Is this you @Pete?  Are you still using Joomla? I would like to get in touch with all Joomla Users in the Brisbane vicinity.